# Keeping Text Format when using RangeToHTML (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am copying a selected range to the body of an Outlook email using RangetoHTML(rng).

My range is a table with headers. When pasted onto the email window using `.Display`, the table headers are unbolded. I tried all of the xlPasteSpecials.

```vb
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
    ' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
      SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
      Filename:=TempFile, _
      Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
      Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
      HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: The rangetoHTML method by Ron de Bruin does indeed not work too well with the current formatting as the data gets delivered using an unformatted array. To get around this you can reapply the formatting in the temp file with something like `Range("A:D").font.bold = true`, you put that in after `.Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False`.

Comment: Is there a way to open up the temp wb so I know which row to specifically re-apply the bold?

Comment: [Insert a breakpoint](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/4/8/debugging-vba-code-adding-breakpoints) at the end of the `'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in` block, and it will halt just after creating the temp file.

Comment: Forgot i had the screenupdating block set to false before. I figured it out. Thanks for your help

Comment: If that's not already part of your post, [edit] so your post is an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Then [write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).